# Error when migrating on-premises TFS to Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration, opshub

I am in the process of migrating our existing TFS 2012 to Visual Studio Online, and I have already migrated 3 of our 5 projects from our own server.

The largest one of our projects, the fourth in the migration queue fails.

Here is the error received:

> Error in execution of Job : teamfoundation\DefaultCollection to [Name
>   Removed].visualstudio.com _1| teamfoundation\DefaultCollection to
>   [Name Removed].visualstudio.com _1| TFS Source 1412855236297 Source
>   TFS 1412855236297 'WebSite' Commit Information 
>   teamfoundation\DefaultCollection to [Name Removed].visualstudio.com
>   _1| TFS Source 1412855236297 Source TFS 1412855236297 TFS Commit Information
>       Fatal Error: One of the end-point not available. Server Error: OpsHub-012013: Process execution failed on node: callMethod, in
>   process definition: 'SCM Default Integration Workflow'; nested
>   exception is : script evaluation exception

I am running *OpsHub Integration Manager Framework-OVSMU-V1.0.1.006*

Here is an image of the error received

[image]
I have tried to restart the process twice, and it times out after about 20 minutes - And gives the same error.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Ed, I did not have enough reputation to add the image myself.

Comment: The error message indicates loss of connection to one of the end point. Can you please ping your end points for some while and see if the response is consistent?

Comment: I figured a way of making this migration work, I started by migrating only the Work Items - And then the Version Control. Then the history was transferred from my local TFS to TFS Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates loss of connection to one of the end point. Can you please ping your end points for some while and see if the response is consistent?

Comment: Running in two steps, first work items and then version control solved it.